# Why is simplexml_load_string failing to get XML value?

Tags: xml

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gallery>
    <image big="image1.jpg"
           thumb="image1t.jpg"/>
    <image big="image2"
           thumb="image2.jpg"/>         
    <image big="image3t.jpg"
           thumb="image3t.jpg"/>
```

I want to access the link in the `big` value, for this I use;

```
<?php
    $xmls = "test.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmls);
    foreach ($xml->image[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $b;
    }
?>
```

Result: Empty white screen.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you looking for `simplexml_load_file()` instead of `simplexml_load_string()`?

Comment: @Progman Yes it worked but Just gave me the information of a picture. How do I get all the picture's values?